# ¿Por qué las cadenas que envío desde Arduino no me llegan completas a Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Estoy enviando varias cadenas por bluetooth desde arduino a Android, al llegar a la aplicación hago subcadenas para poder obtener los datos que necesito. Sin embargo, las cadenas están llegando mal, se cortan y por lo tanto no puedo obtener las substrings que necesito. Por ejemplo: Desde Arduino mando cadenas de este estilo: `#ecg{21304(2.41~`

Al enviar varias cadenas en el monitor serial de arduino se ven asi:

> `#ecg{21304(2.41~#ecg{21324(3.37~#ecg{21324(1.98~#ecg{21345(3.14~#ecg{21345(3.05~#ecg{21365(1.98~#...`

Pero cuando llegan al celular llegar cortadas, algo como esto:

```
g{ 21304(2.41 ~#e cg{21324(3.37~#ec g{21324(1.98~#ecg{21345(3. 14~#ecg {21345(3.05~#ecg{21365(1.98~#...
```

[Observese que desde un inicio no están llegando completas en la mayoría de los casos]
Y por tanto no puedo haces las substrings de los datos que necesito.
 ¿Saben por qué se cortan y no llegan completas a como las envío desde el arduino?
¿Hay manera de solucionarlo?

La recepción de cadenas incompletas podría deberse a la velocidad de transmisión usada en el código Arduino (115200)?
Hice pruebas cargando un programa  en otro arduino que envía datos via bluetooth a la misma app y estos llegan bien, la diferencia es que esté envía los datos  a 9600

Este es el código de las cadenas que envio desde arduino:

```c
#include <eHealth.h>
  float datosECG[200], ImprimeDatosECG[100]; 
  float PosPar;
  int pos,i,cont=0;
  unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
  const long intervaloRequerido = 200;


// The setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

// The loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {

      unsigned currentMillis = millis();

if(eHealth.getECG()>0.5)
{
  for(i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
    pos=i;
    datosECG[i] = eHealth.getECG();
//    Serial.println(datosECG[i]);    
    PosPar = pos%50;//Con 50 conecta el bluetooth pero no envia datos por bluetooth y la grafica pierde mucha informacion

    if(PosPar==0)
    {
                    Serial.print('#'); 
                    Serial.print("ecg"); 
                    Serial.print('{'); 
                    Serial.print(currentMillis);
                    Serial.print('('); 
                    Serial.print(datosECG[i]);
                    Serial.print('~');       
    }
  }
  delay(1); // wait for a millisecond
}

}
```

Esta es la parte donde se hace el procesamiento para hacer las subcadenas:

```java
            switch (msg.what) {

            case CONST.MSG_LEER:
                String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
                recDataString.append(readMessage);

                int charInicioCadena = recDataString.indexOf("#");
                int charInicioTiempo = recDataString.indexOf("{");
                //int charFinTiempo = recDataString.indexOf("}");
                int charInicioValor = recDataString.indexOf("(");
                //int charFinValor = recDataString.indexOf(")");
                int charFinCadena = recDataString.indexOf("~");



                System.out.println("Pos de Caracter de Inicio de cadena: "+charInicioCadena);
                System.out.println("Pos de Caracter de Inicio de tiempo: "+charInicioTiempo);
                //System.out.println("Pos de Caracter de fin de tiempo: "+charFinTiempo);
                System.out.println("Pos de Caracter de Inicio de valor: "+charInicioValor);
                //System.out.println("Pos de Caracter de fin de valor: "+charFinValor);
                System.out.println("Pos de Caracter de fin de cadena: "+charFinCadena);



                if (charFinCadena > 0) {

                    nombreDispositivo = recDataString.substring(charInicioCadena + 1, charInicioTiempo);

                    switch (nombreDispositivo) {
                        case "ecg":

                            segundo = recDataString.substring(charInicioTiempo + 1, charInicioValor);
                            valorECG = recDataString.substring(charInicioValor + 1, charFinCadena);
                            System.out.println("Dispositivo: " + nombreDispositivo);
                            System.out.println("segundo: " + segundo);
                            System.out.println("Valor ECG: " + valorECG);
                            Globals.lstSendSegundoECG.add(segundo+";"+valorECG);
                            System.out.println("Valor de la lista: " + Globals.lstSendSegundoECG);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                }

                break;
```

Esta es la parte donde envío los datos que llegan del bluetooth a la actividad principal:

```java
            while (mState == STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                String outputText="";
                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);                   
                mDataParse.Add(buffer, bytes);
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                System.out.println("Datos del Arduino: "+readMessage);

                mHandler.obtainMessage(CONST.MSG_LEER,bytes,-1,readMessage).sendToTarget();//lindonde se envian los datos a la actividad principal
```

Esta es una salida del debug de la consola de android:

```
12/29 17:41:03: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\Javier\AndroidStudioProjects\BotonMedicoAmunet\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.botonmedico.amunet
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.botonmedico.amunet"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.botonmedico.amunet
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.botonmedico.amunet/com.botonmedico.amunet.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Connecting to com.botonmedico.amunet
W/ActivityThread: Application com.botonmedico.amunet is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8668', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1381)
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/Atlas: Validating map...
I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
              OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
              Build Date: 02/11/15 Wed
              Local Branch: 
              Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.10
              Local Patches: NONE
              Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016 + 62ca4eb + acd831d + 9f8b442 + e027a02 + cba30ba + 53c303a + a649d79 + 23e16f8 + 5e97da7 + cbd2a44 + 33d072a + 7aacf06 + 72b33e7 + 28f6f60 + b4c13d8 +  NOTHING
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
I/System.out: Entrando al onSuccess
I/BluetoothUtils: -----startDiscovery----
I/BluetoothUtils: Get BT device   name:BotonMedicoBT  mac:00:07:80:B3:96:4C
D/BluetoothChatService: connect to: 00:07:80:B3:96:4C
D/BluetoothChatService: setState() 0 -> 2
I/BluetoothChatService: BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:Secure
W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
I/BluetoothUtils: -----finishDiscovery----
D/BluetoothChatService: connected, Socket Type:Secure
D/BluetoothChatService: create ConnectedThread: Secure
I/System.out: Bluet: { when=-4h10m40s40ms what=1 target=com.botonmedico.amunet.MainActivity$1 }
D/BluetoothChatService: setState() 2 -> 3
I/BluetoothChatService: BEGIN mConnectedThread
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: #ecg{2
I/System.out: Pos de Caracter de Inicio de cadena: 0
I/System.out: Pos de Caracter de Inicio de tiempo: 4
I/System.out: Pos de Caracter de Inicio de valor: -1
I/System.out: Pos de Caracter de fin de cadena: -1
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 0144(2.26~#ecg{20164(2.62~#ecg{20164(3.25~#ecg{20185(1.76~#ecg{20185(3.38~
I/System.out: Pos de Caracter de Inicio de cadena: 10
I/System.out: Pos de Caracter de Inicio de tiempo: 14
I/System.out: Pos de Caracter de Inicio de valor: 4
I/System.out: Pos de Caracter de fin de cadena: 9
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.botonmedico.amunet, PID: 17532
                  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=74; regionStart=15; regionLength=-11
                      at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.startEndAndLength(AbstractStringBuilder.java:211)
                      at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(AbstractStringBuilder.java:616)
                      at java.lang.StringBuilder.substring(StringBuilder.java:44)
                      at com.botonmedico.amunet.MainActivity$1.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:274)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: #ecg{20205(2.81~#ecg{20205(
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 2.50~#ecg{20226(3.36~#ecg{20226(1.79~#ecg{20246(3.16~#ecg{20246(2.89~#ecg{20267(2.02~#ecg{202
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 67(3.38~#ecg{20286(2.17~#ecg{20286(3.05~#ecg{20306(3.19~#
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: ecg{20306(1.93~#ecg{20327(3.37~#ecg{20327(2.30~#ecg{20347(2.58~#ecg{
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 20347(3.27~#ecg{20368(1.76~#ecg{20368(3.40~#ecg{20388(2.83~#ecg{20388(2.47~#ecg{20409(3.37~
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: #ecg{20409(1.81~#ecg{20429(3.16~#ecg{20429(2.94~#ecg{20449(2.01~#ecg{
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 20449(3.37~#ecg{20469(2.30~#ecg{20469(3.04~#ecg{20490(3.25~#ecg{20490
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: (1.94~#ecg{20510(3.40~
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: #ecg{20510(2.33~#ecg{20531(2.57~#ecg{20531(3.26~#ecg{20551(1.77~#ecg{20551(3.37~#ecg{20572(2.84~#ecg{20572(2.39~#ecg{20592(3.
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 33~#ecg{20592(1.85~#ecg{20612(3.09~#ecg{20612(2.96~#ecg{20632(1.96~#e
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: cg{20632(3.44~#ecg{20653(2.24~#ecg{20653(2.96~
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: #ecg{20673(3.23~#ecg{20673(1.89~#ecg{20694(3.37~#ecg{20694(2.41~#ecg{20714(2.47~#
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: ecg{20714(3.28~#ecg{20734(1.79~#ecg{20734(3.37~
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: #ecg{20754(2.90~#ecg{20754(2.47~#ecg{20774(3.36~#ecg{20774
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: (1.85~#ecg{20795(3.11~#ecg{20795(3.01~#ecg{20815(1.96~#
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: ecg{20815(3.37~#ecg{20836(2.29~#ecg{20836(2.96~#ecg{20856(3.25~#ecg{20856(1.86~#ecg{20877(3.39~#
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: ecg{20877(2.42~#ecg{20897(2.49~#ecg{20897(3.29~#ecg{20917(1.81~#ecg{209
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 17(3.40~#ecg{20937(2.92~#ecg{20937(2.36~#ecg{20958(3.39~#ecg{20958(1.86~#ecg
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: {20978(3.03~#ecg{20978(2.49~#ecg{20999(1.49~#ecg{20999(3.25~
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: #ecg{21019(2.31~#ecg{21019(3.11~#ecg{21040(3.27~#ecg{21040(1.97~#ecg{21060(3
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: .49~#ecg{21060(2.48~#ecg{21080(2.59~#
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: ecg{21080(3.28~#ecg{21100(1.87~#ecg{21100(3.48~#ecg{21121(2.94~#
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: ecg{21121(2.47~#ecg{21141(3.38~#ecg{21141(1.95~#ecg{21161(3.20~#ecg{21161(3.01~#ecg
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: {21182(2.02~#ecg{21182(3.48~#ecg{21202(2.37~#ecg{21202(3.09~#ecg{21223(3.26~#
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: ecg{21223(1.92~#ecg{21242(3.48~#ecg{21242(2.52~#
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: ecg{21263(2.59~#ecg{21263(3.31~#ecg{21283(1.92~#ecg{21283(3.48~#ecg{21304(2.99~
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: #ecg{21304(2.41~#ecg{21324(3.37~#ecg{21324(1.98~#ecg{21345(3.14~#ecg{21345(3.05~#ecg{21365(1.98~#
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: ecg{21365(3.40~#ecg{21386(2.42~#ecg{21386(3.00~#ecg{21405(3.29~#
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: ecg{21405(1.89~#ecg{21426(3.47~#ecg{21426(2.55~#ecg{21446(2.49~#ecg{21446(3.33~#
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: ecg{21467(1.92~#ecg{21467(3.48~#ecg{21487(3.00~#ecg{21487(2.43~#ecg{21508(3.39~#ecg{21508(1.9
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 8~#ecg{21528(3.11~#ecg{21528(3.12~#ecg{21549(1.96~#ecg
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: {21549(3.42~#ecg{21569(2.49~#ecg{21569(2.97~
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: #ecg{21588(3.32~#ecg{21588(1.87~#ecg{21609(3.47~#ecg{21609(2.61~#ecg{21629(2.47~#ecg{21629(3.34~#ecg{21650(1.96~#ecg{2
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 1650(3.46~#ecg{21670(3.03~#ecg{21670(2.36~#ecg{21691(3.40~#e
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: cg{21691(2.04~#ecg{21711(3.04~
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: #ecg{21711(3.10~#ecg{21731(1.90~#ecg{21731(3.37~#ecg{21751(2.50~#ecg{21751(2.91~#ecg{21772
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: (3.29~#ecg{21772(1.85~#ecg{21792(3.45~#ecg{21792(2.68~#ecg{21813(2.40~#ecg
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: {21813(3.45~#ecg{21833(2.02~#ecg{21833(3.25~#ecg{21854(2.98~#ecg{
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 21854(2.28~#ecg{21874(3.39~#ecg{218
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 74(2.06~#ecg{21894(2.99~#ecg{21894(3.17~#ecg{21914(1.89~#ecg{21914(3.41~#ecg{21935(2.57~#ecg{219
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 35(2.90~#ecg{21955(3.32~#ecg{21955(1.87~#ecg{21976(3.34~#
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: ecg{21976(2.72~#ecg{21996(1.72~#ecg{21996(3.10~#ecg{22017(1.95~
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: #ecg{22017(3.09~#ecg{22037(2.28~#ecg{22037(1.12~
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: #ecg{22056(3.24~#ecg{22056(2.07~#ecg{22077(2.83~#ecg{22077(3.19~#ecg{22097(1.77~#
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: ecg{22097(3.39~#ecg{22118(2.52~#ecg{22118(2.83~#ecg{22138(3.32~#ecg{22
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 138(1.88~#ecg{22159(3.43~#ecg{22159(2.71~#ecg{22179(
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 2.34~#ecg{22179(3.32~#ecg{22200(2.02~#ecg{22200(3.36~#ecg{22219(3.10~#ecg{22219(2.25~
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: #ecg{22240(3.40~#ecg{22240(2.16~#ecg{22260(2.91~#ecg{22260(3.17~#ec
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: g{22281(1.85~#ecg{22281(3.44~#ecg{22301(2.63~
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17532 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8668', transport: 'socket'
```

Espero en verdad que me puedan ayudar con mi problema, de antemano gracias.

Comment: obviamente los datos no incluyen la cadena `<br>`, ¿qué es realmente lo que recibes?

Comment: esto es lo que se ve que esta entrando:

<code>
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: #ecg{20205(2.81~#ecg{20205(
I/System.out: Datos del Arduino: 2.50~#ecg{20226(3.36~#ecg{20226(1.79~#ecg{20246(3.16~#ecg{20246(2.89~#ecg{20267(2.02~#ecg{202...

</code>

Comment: Xavi, puedes editar tu pregunta para mostrar los datos reales que recibes. En comentarios no es el lugar más adecuado.

Comment: La función println envia byte a byte los datos, por lo que no llegaran juntos todos los datos, te recomiendo usar un buffer e implementar una máquina de estado para veríficar los datos. Además usa union para enviar los datos de tipo float ya que si lo envias como string(print convierte el dato float a string) enviarás más bytes de los necesario. por ejemplo cuando envias 12222, estarás enviando 5 bytes, en cambio si usas una unión enviarás solamente 4

Comment: Usé un buffer como el de este post pero  no me funciono: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885408/byte-array-to-string-till-n

Comment: Cómo sería el buffer que tú sugieres ?

Comment: La recepción de cadenas incompletas podría deberse a la velocidad de transmisión usada en el código Arduino (115200)?
Hice pruebas cargando un programa  en otro arduino que envía datos via bluetooth a la misma app y estos llegan bien, la diferencia es que esté envía los datos  a 9600

Answer (score 1):

Como bien dice @jachguate `<br>` nunca se han enviado y no se puede recibir.

En los comentarios agregaste información... esto es lo que recibes relmente:

```
2.50~#ecg{20226(3.36~#ecg{20226(1.79~#ecg{20246(3.16~#ecg{20‌​246(2.89~#ecg{20267(‌​2.02~#ecg{202
```

Y que esto esperas:
    #ecg{21304(2.41~#ecg{21324(3.37~#ecg{21324(1.98~#ecg{21345(3.14~#ecg{21345(3.05~#ecg{21365(

Por lo que sospecho de los `substring` que realizas es el incorrecto.

```
segundo = recDataString.substring(charInicioTiempo + 1, charInicioValor);
valorECG = recDataString.substring(charInicioValor + 1, charFinCadena);
```

Si lo que buscas es separar la cadena puedes usar la función `split("string que indica una separación")`, creo que en tu caso debes separar usando un `split("~")` y usar string.replace("caracter(es) no deseados", "") para remover los signos que no quieras

Comment: Buen dia, lo hice con splits como dijiste y en efecto puedo separar cadenas, pero sigo teniendo el mismo inconveniente, dado que las cadenas llegan 
`.50~#ecg{20226`
`(3.36~#ecg{20226(1.79~`
`#ecg{20246(3.16~`
#ecg{20‌​246`  
Cuando separo por tokens me separa  asi 
`.50  ecg 2022 3.336`
`ecg 20246 3.16`
`ecg 20246`

Las separación de cadenas que yo esperaría serian de este tipo:
`ecg 20246 3.16` Donde tengo el nombre del dispositivo, el tiempo en ms y el valor.
Es por esto que pienso que la separación esta bien, lo que esta mal es la recepción de los datos.

Comment: Encontré un post con un problema similar, en el hacen uso de un buffer como implementacion para que las cadenas que vallan llegando se vallan almacenando en otro string  hasta que llegue cierto caracter, pero no me resulto. Este es el post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885408/byte-array-to-string-till-n

Comment: sigo pensando que la cadena llega desordenada producto del substring(primerCaracter, ultimoCaracter)

Comment: Creo que te estas confundiendo.  A mi parecer esto no tiene que ver pues primero llega la cadena por bluetooth y una vez recibida se hacen los substrings.

Comment: no se muy bien como seguir ayudándote, podrías inicar la aplicación en modo debug para ver que se envía-recepciona... y probar si ocrre en otros dispositivos. Si es siempre el error, y con el mismo patron (ej: 5 caracteres), podrías por ejemplo, mover el corte del inicio de la cadena al final, asignandolo por ejemplo de la siguiente manera... substring(5, cadena.length()) +  substring(0, 4)... se que no es una solución correcta, pero es mejor a no tener una solución

Answer (score 0):

por que lo estas enviando asi con cada `Serial.print('texto');` se le agrega un `\n` salto de linea prueba poniendo todo junto.

Comment: Buen dia, lo puse todo junto de esta manera: 
`CadenaUno="#ecg{"; 
CadenaDos="("; 
CadenaTres="~"; 
CadenaFinal=CadenaUno+currentMillis+CadenaDos+ecgValue+Caden‌​aTres; Serial.println(CadenaFinal);` 
Pero me siguen llegando cortadas.

Comment: Creo que el error esta en _Esta es la parte donde envío los datos que llegan del bluetooth a la actividad principal_ intenta modificar el tamaño del buffer

Comment: Ya lo intenté, Si cambio el tamaño del buffer a por ejemplo 512  me siguen llegando las cadenas cortadas.